# Convert a MySql query into Yii2 ActiveQuery

Tags: php, yii2

There is a query I want to convert into the ActiveQuery models in Yii2:

the query:

```
SELECT * FROM commodity where ( code like "1122%" or code like "1111%" ) and
            ( subid = 19 or subid = 323 ) order by name asc
```

There is the model:

```
class Commodity extends ActiveRecord
{
    ...
}
```

the format which I want to achieve for-example:

```
Commodity::find()->where()->andWhere()->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

```
$models = Commodity::find()
    ->where(['or like', 'code', ['1122%', '1111%'], false])
    ->andWhere(['subid' => [19, 323]])
    ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])
    ->all();
```